# Store large image

Tags: database, image, data-structures, image-processing

I'm looking for a way to store a very large image (e.g. 100.000x100.000 pixels) on a webserver. I must be able to retrieve parts of that image and write parts into it. The cherry on top would be a way to get parts of that image, resized to a specific resolution (for example, i want alle pixels from 0,0 to 10.000,10.000 resized to 1000x1000 pixels).

Anybody know a kind of DB, or a data-structure or any other way or service or programm that can handle something like that?

thx, tux

Comment: What server side languages do you have available?

Comment: If it was not for the write-part Silverlight DeepZoom would be a possible alternative. https://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/deepzoom/

Comment: it would be ruby on rails on the server side.
silverlight is not a good solution for my (cause i don't know it ;)), as3 would be the choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How about Tiles?**

Just like what popular mapping application (Google Maps / Bing Maps ) does. Divide and pre-process your image in to tiles for various sizes (zoom levels). Display them on a webpage with zero margin, zero border.

While retrieving, calculate positioning of tiles (which tiles should be retrieved as whole and which ones as partial) and then return as single image.

http://143.117.54.5/idl/images/img_pyrm.gif

(image ack: http://143.117.54.5/idl/Image_Tiling.html)

Answer (score 1):

Search for "map servers": there are a bunch of them already available. I'm sure they at least contain components that might be of interest for you.

Comment: thx for your answer! We develop in ruby on rails, do you know any good solution for a map server? I can't find anyone